# How do I PREVENT my app from asking for permission to access photos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, camera, avfoundation

I'm making an app which records video. I'm saving the video to the app's sandbox, and hence I have no need to access the users photo library. I don't want my app to ask for permission ever. HOWEVER, about 50% of the time the app opens, it asks for permission to access photos.

My best guess at the cause: I am using a library which makes it easier to work with AV Foundation, and it has some feature buried in it's code which is triggering the permission dialog.

What's the best way to make sure the dialog never appears? Can I override it by setting a firm NO somewhere in my app's plist? Do I have to root through the library's code to find the offending feature? If so, what's the best way to identify the culprit? What's most likely to be triggering the dialog?

The libraries I'm using:

DIYAV:    https://github.com/diy/av

DIYCam: https://github.com/thisandagain/cam

I'm triggering recording like this:

```
// self.cam is a DIYCam instance
[self.cam startSession];
[self.cam captureVideoStart];
```

and stopping recording like this:

```
[self.cam captureVideoStop];
[self.cam stopSession];
```

Comment: I bet the library is using `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo it is, but from what I can tell its only to run isSourceTypeAvailable

Comment: @JoshCaswell added the libraries and links, sorry for the omission. Also, I'll add some code I'm using.

Comment: Is it possible that by replacing your app's sandbox when you build and go, that your app is getting removed from the permissions chain?  Try running the thing without building before jumping to the conclusion that the permissions dialog is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search the framework and you have the code, you should search for  `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`

These are the ones, that access the iPhone photo library.

Comment: It has neither. But it does have AVAsset methods such as AVAssetImageGenerator. Do those trigger the permissions dialog?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know, you don't ever need any AVAsset code. In my application, I implemented my own photo shooting, and I didn't need AVAsset at all ( I don't have any reference to AVAsset in my code ). you could try to comment out all the parts, that contain the AVAsset. Did you also think about using a different framework? I know DIYCamera is pretty easy to use and when I remembre correctly if you just used the camera part it didn't ask you for photo access permission!

Comment: DIYCamera is actually the library I'm using. I added the links to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "DIYAVSettingSaveLibrary" to false seems to have solved it. (It's set to true by default.)

```
NSDictionary *options;
options          = @{ DIYAVSettingFlash              : @false,
                      DIYAVSettingOrientationForce   : @false,
                      DIYAVSettingOrientationDefault : [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight],
                      DIYAVSettingCameraPosition     : [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack],
                      DIYAVSettingCameraHighISO      : @true,
                      DIYAVSettingPhotoPreset        : AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto,
                      DIYAVSettingPhotoGravity       : AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill,
                      DIYAVSettingVideoPreset        : AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720,
                      DIYAVSettingVideoGravity       : AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill,
                      DIYAVSettingVideoMaxDuration   : @300,
                      DIYAVSettingVideoFPS           : @30,
                      DIYAVSettingSaveLibrary        : @false };

[cam setupWithOptions:options]; // Check DIYAV.h for options
[cam setCamMode:DIYAVModeVideo];
```

Comment: Don't suppose you could share your code for saving to the sandbox through DIYCAM?  Documentation is a little slim for DIYAV/DIYCAM...